# asp.net membership create user error

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-membership

I encountered an issue while creating users using the asp.net user membership. The membership provider configuration is as follows-

```
<add name="SqlProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider"
    connectionStringName="DBConnection" applicationName="App"
    enablePasswordRetrieval="true" enablePasswordReset="true"
    requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="true"
    passwordFormat="Encrypted" />
```

The error generated by ASP.net configuration application is as follows-

```
An error was encountered. Please return to the previous page and try again. 

The following message may help in diagnosing the problem: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
at System.RuntimeMethodHandle._InvokeMethodFast(IRuntimeMethodInfo method, Object target, Object[] arguments, SignatureStruct& sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeType typeOwner)
at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethodFast(IRuntimeMethodInfo method, Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeType typeOwner)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
at System.Web.Administration.WebAdminMembershipProvider.CallWebAdminMembershipProviderHelperMethodOutParams(String methodName, Object[] parameters, Type[] paramTypes)
at System.Web.Administration.WebAdminMembershipProvider.CreateUser(String username, String password, String email, String passwordQuestion, String passwordAnswer, Boolean isApproved, Object providerUserKey, MembershipCreateStatus& status)
at System.Web.UI.WebControls.CreateUserWizard.AttemptCreateUser()
at System.Web.UI.WebControls.CreateUserWizard.OnNextButtonClick(WizardNavigationEventArgs e)
at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Wizard.OnBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs e)
at System.Web.UI.WebControls.CreateUserWizard.OnBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs e)
at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Wizard.WizardChildTable.OnBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs args)
at System.Web.UI.Control.RaiseBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs args)
at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnCommand(CommandEventArgs e)
at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)
at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)
at System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument)
at System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData)
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
```

Comment: Where is the exception message, what you copied is stack trace. Check Debug->Exceptions->Common Language Runtime Exceptions to catch the exception and see the message.

Comment: Plus: can you **show us** the code you're using to create a user??

Comment: That seems to be the <machineKey> issue as discussed here: http://forums.asp.net/t/910729.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just got the same error and indeed, @gbs's answer within the comments above is correct.
Machinekey needs to be set in system.web of the webconfig as indicated [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/910729.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Check the InnerException, there's your answer.